# How to pass the id inside of the column index Angular

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, rxjs

I'm trying to pass my response id to this.names[i].ArrayListID per column index but it won't get it. how to achieve that?

```
export interface Names {
  ArrayListID: number;
  itemName: string;
}


names: Names[] = [];
responseID:any;
```

this.names

```
[Array[2]]
   0: Array[2]
    0: Object
    ArrayListID: 0
    itemName: "TEST001A"
    <prototype>: Object
   1: Object
    ArrayListID: 0
    itemName: "TEST001B"
    <prototype>: Object
```

i get the response.id but it won't fill the ArrayListID in this.names[i].

```
 onSave() {
  for(let id of this.formGroup.value){
  this.services.PostID(id).subscribe((response)=>{
    this.responseID = response.id
    for (let i = 0; i < this.names.length; i++) {
      this.names[i].ArrayListID = this.responseID
     this.services.PostArray(this.names[i]).subscribe((res)=>{
      console.log(res)
      })
    }
   })
  }
  }
```

Comment: Are you sure `this.responseID` has a value other different from `0`? If possible post a [mre].

Comment: Secondly, a little recommendation: your pipe could be improved by using `concatMap` (or it siblings) with `forkJoin` to avoid the nested `subscribe`-handler.

Comment: @churill this.responseID has a example id like this 0: id: 1, 1: id: 2